# I want the output to adapt to age

Tags: java

```
public class nbaPlayers {

int draftRank;
String playerName;
String playerTeam;
int playerAge;
int rank;

public nbaPlayers(String name, String team, int age, int collegeRank) {
    name = this.playerName;
    team = this.playerTeam;
    age = this.playerAge;
    collegeRank = this.draftRank;
}

public void setRating() {
    if (playerAge < 21 && draftRank <=3) {
        rank = 95;
    }
    else if (playerAge >=21 || draftRank <= 25) {
        rank = 80;
    }
    else if (playerAge >25 || draftRank >=30 ) {
        rank = 60;
    }
    else if (draftRank >= 30 || draftRank <=50) {
        rank = 45;
    }
    else {
        rank = 10;  
    }
}

public int getRating() {
    return rank;
}

}

public class helloWorld {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

  nbaPlayers player1 = new nbaPlayers("Kyrie", "Duke",18,7);
  nbaPlayers player2 = new nbaPlayers("D-Book", "Kentucky",18,4);
  nbaPlayers player3 = new nbaPlayers("LBJ", "None",34,1);

  player1.setRating();
  System.out.println("This player rating is: " + player1.getRating());
  player2.setRating();
  System.out.println("This player rating is: " + player2.getRating());
  player3.setRating();      
  System.out.println("This player rating is: " + player3.getRating());

  }
}
```

What is the problem with the output, as the values keeps saying the initial rank which is 95?
I want the rating to change since the age for LeBron is 34. 
P.S java only makes sense when i compared it to things in interested in.

Answer (score 2):

You need to flip your constructor assignments:

```
this.playerName = name;
this.playerTeam = team;
this.playerAge = age;
this.draftRank = collegeRank;
```

Comment: Is this always what should be done when constructing ? the name, team, age, and collegeRank are all inputs, should it always be constructed this way? Thanks.

Comment: `this` refer to the instance being constructed, the way you did before, you were assigning values to the constructor's parameters

Answer (score 0):

You would also need to fix the comparison on 4th if statement:

```
else if (draftRank >= 30 || draftRank <=50) {
    rank = 45;
}
```

What are you trying to do here with both same fields? also 3rd if statement has the same field too.

Comment: I have fixed this issue and the output is printing as it should

Answer (score 0):

Issues with your sample program:

- the constructors are not flipped properly
- variables are not explicitly declared
- test values are not clear enough

Please compare this re-written nbPayer with yours:

```
public class nbaPlayers {

    private int draftRank;
    private String playerName;
    private String playerTeam;
    private int playerAge;
    private int rank;

    public nbaPlayers(String name, String team, int age, int collegeRank) {
        // constructors assignment has to be flipped as mentioned
        this.playerName = name;
        this.playerTeam = team;
        this.playerAge = age;
        this.draftRank = collegeRank;
    }

    public void setRating() {
        if (playerAge < 21 && draftRank <=3) {
            rank = 95;
        }
        else if (playerAge >=21 || draftRank <= 25) {
            rank = 80;
        }
        else if (playerAge >25 || draftRank >=30 ) {
            rank = 60;
        }
        else if (draftRank >= 30 || draftRank <=50) {
            rank = 45;
        }
        else {
            rank = 10;
        }
    }

    public int getRating() {
        return rank;
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        // also take note of your test values
        nbaPlayers player1 = new nbaPlayers( "Kyrie", "Duke", 18, 1 );
        nbaPlayers player2 = new nbaPlayers( "D-Book", "Kentucky", 20, 1 );
        nbaPlayers player3 = new nbaPlayers( "LBJ", "None", 34, 1 );

        player1.setRating();
        System.out.println( "Player 1 rating is: " + player1.getRating() );
        player2.setRating();
        System.out.println( "Player 2 rating is: " + player2.getRating() );
        player3.setRating();
        System.out.println( "Player 3 rating is: " + player3.getRating() );

    }
}
```

The output of the re-written class is this:

```
Player 1 rating is: 95
Player 2 rating is: 95
Player 3 rating is: 80
```

Comment: I have fixed this issue and the output is printing as it should. TY.

Answer (score 0):

setRating() method is wrong. eg, you should begin the if from the biggist number, like this:
if(age > 90){}
if(age > 80){}

This can make sure one age only enter one if.